# Tricky conversion of field names to values while performing row by row de-aggregation (using Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to convert specific field names to values while performing a de aggregation the values into their own unique rows as well as perform a long pivot.

**Data**

```
Start       Date        End         Area    Final       Type    Middle Stat Low Stat    High Stat  Middle Stat1 Low Stat1    High Stat1
8/1/2013    9/1/2013    10/1/2013   NY      3/1/2023    CC      226         20          10         0             0            0
8/1/2013    9/1/2013    10/1/2013   CA      3/1/2023    AA      130         50          0          0             0            0






data = {
    "Start": ['8/1/2013', '8/1/2013'],
    "Date": ['9/1/2013', '9/1/2013'],
    "End": ['10/1/2013', '10/1/2013'],
    "Area": ['NY', 'CA'],
    "Final": ['3/1/2023', '3/1/2023'],
    "Type": ['CC', 'AA'],
    "Middle Stat": [226, 130],
    "Low Stat": [20, 50],
    "High Stat": [10, 0],
    "Middle Stat1": [0, 0],
    "Low Stat1": [0, 0],
    "High Stat1": [0, 0]
}
```

**Desired**

```
Start       Date        End         Area    Final       Type    Stat    Range   Stat1
8/1/2013    9/1/2013    10/1/2013   NY      3/1/2023    CC      20      Low     0
8/1/2013    9/1/2013    10/1/2013   CA      3/1/2023    AA      50      Low     0
8/1/2013    9/1/2013    10/1/2013   NY      3/1/2023    CC      226     Middle  0
8/1/2013    9/1/2013    10/1/2013   CA      3/1/2023    AA      130     Middle  0
8/1/2013    9/1/2013    10/1/2013   NY      3/1/2023    CC      10      High    0
8/1/2013    9/1/2013    10/1/2013   CA      3/1/2023    AA      0       High    0
```

**Doing**

I believe I have to inject some sort of wide to long method, (SO member assisted) however unsure how to incorporate this whilst having the same suffix in the targeted (columns of interest) column names.

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                stubnames=['Low','Middle','High'],
                i=['Start','Date','End','Area','Final'],
                j='',
                sep=' ',
                suffix='(stat)'
).unstack(level=-1, fill_value=0).stack(level=0).reset_index()
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

**#Original Dataset**

```
import pandas as pd

# create DataFrame
data = {'Start': ['9/1/2013', '10/1/2013', '11/1/2013', '12/1/2013'],
        'Date': ['10/1/2016', '11/1/2016', '12/1/2016', '1/1/2017'],
        'End': ['11/1/2016', '12/1/2016', '1/1/2017', '2/1/2017'],
        'Area': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY'],
        'Final': ['3/1/2023', '3/1/2023', '3/1/2023', '3/1/2023'],
        'Type': ['CC', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC'],
        'Low Stat': ['', '', '', ''],
        'Low Stat1': ['', '', '', ''],
        'Middle Stat': ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
        'Middle Stat1': ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
        'Re': ['','','',''],
        'Set': ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
        'Set2': ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
        'Set3': ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
        'High Stat': ['', '', '', ''],
        'High Stat1': ['', '', '', '']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: it would be easier to reproduce if you provide your data as a dictionary

Comment: Ok noted - I will update in a bit

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy I updated thank you for informing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) - in this case we use the special placeholder `.value` to identify the parts of the column that we want to remain as headers, while the rest get collated into a new column :

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = slice('Start', 'Type'), 
    names_to = ("Range", ".value"), 
    names_sep = " ")
)
      Start      Date        End Area     Final Type   Range  Stat  Stat1
0  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023   CC  Middle   226      0
1  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023   AA  Middle   130      0
2  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023   CC     Low    20      0
3  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023   AA     Low    50      0
4  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023   CC    High    10      0
5  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023   AA    High     0      0
```

Comment: thank you this works, but it is cutting off some of my other columns. I suppose that is due to the slicing. I updated the original problem with what my true dataset looks like. @sammywemmy
Is there a work around the slicing ? Thank you

Comment: @Lynn Do you also need to update the desired output for the true dataset example?

Comment: I will create new problem yes thank you

Answer (score 2):

```py
df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[:6], value_name='Values')
```

```
      Start      Date        End Area     Final Type     variable  Values
0  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023   CC  Middle Stat    226
1  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023   AA  Middle Stat    130
2  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023   CC    Low Stat      20
3  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023   AA    Low Stat      50
4  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023   CC   High Stat      10
5  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023   AA   High Stat       0
```

Comment: Trick : if you want to get rid of `Stat`, you should simply rename your columns before merging and that's all :-) `df.columns = [...]`

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense @Lauret B. This is a slick one liner- is there a special way to handle the additional 3 columns labeled Stat1 (I have made a slight update)

Comment: Yes sure, just convert first columns to lists `df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[:6].tolist()+df.columns[-3:].tolist(), value_name='Values')`

Comment: to reorder : `r =df[[...order you want...]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to rename the columns first:

```py
import re

df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'(Low|Middle|High) Stat', r'Stat\1', x))

x = pd.wide_to_long(df,
                stubnames='Stat',
                i=['Start','Date','End','Area','Final'],
                j='Range', suffix=r'(?:Low|Middle|High)').reset_index()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
      Start      Date        End Area     Final   Range Type  Stat
0  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023  Middle   CC   226
1  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023     Low   CC    20
2  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023    High   CC    10
3  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023  Middle   AA   130
4  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023     Low   AA    50
5  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023    High   AA     0
```

---

EDIT: To have more stub-names:

```py
import re

df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r"(Low|Middle|High) Stat$", r"Stat\1", x))
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r"(Low|Middle|High) Stat1$", r"1Stat\1", x))

x = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        df,
        stubnames=["Stat", "1Stat"],
        i=["Start", "Date", "End", "Area", "Final"],
        j="Range",
        suffix=r"(?:Low|Middle|High)",
    )
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"1Stat": "Stat1"})
)
```

Prints:

```
      Start      Date        End Area     Final   Range Type  Stat  Stat1
0  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023  Middle   CC   226      0
1  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023     Low   CC    20      0
2  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   NY  3/1/2023    High   CC    10      0
3  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023  Middle   AA   130      0
4  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023     Low   AA    50      0
5  8/1/2013  9/1/2013  10/1/2013   CA  3/1/2023    High   AA     0      0
```

Comment: Hello - my original dataset has columns : Middle Stat, Low Stat,    High Stat, and Middle Stat1, Low Stat1  ,  High Stat1. Could I just add the extra column names to your code? ex. df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'(Low|Middle|High) Stat',  Stat1, r'Stat\1', x))?? Thank you @Andrej Kesely

Comment: @Lynn What should be the desired output in this case? Can you edit your question and put the input/expected output there?

Comment: Hi @Andrej Kesely - I have updated to showcase what I am trying to convey in my dataframe. Please if you can suggest

Comment: ok I am getting this error: ValueError: the id variables need to uniquely identify each row - I will try and troubleshoot